# Extract array elements from a JSON response in tsung, array being the root of the response

Tags: tsung

I am using tsung 1.6 and I have a configuration file in which one of the requests return the following response.

Response:

```
[
  { key: value1 },
  { key: value2 }
]
```

My goal is to extract some variables items from the response and use them further. To be specific I would like to extract `value1` and `value2` in a dynamic variable. The following is what I am doing

```
<request>
  <dyn_variable name="value1" jsonpath="$[0].key"/>
  <dyn_variable name="value2" jsonpath="$[1].key"/>

  <http url='/get.json' version='1.1' method='GET'></http>
</request>

<request subst="true">
  <http
    url='/patch/%%_value1%%'
    version='1.1' 
    contents='{&quot;notified&quot;:true}'
    content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8'
    method='PATCH'
  />
</request>
```

The above is not giving me anything.

The `$[0]` syntax is something that I took from [this](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) site. This was referenced in the tsung documentation, however tsung also mentioned that it implements a very limited subset of the jsonpath.

Need help in extracting the following data.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.g.

test.json:
[{"a":1},{"b":2}]

tsung.xml:

```
<request>
<dyn_variable name="Result" jsonpath="$.[0].a"/>
<http url='/test.json' version='1.1' method='GET'></http>
</request>
```

p.s.
The test.json file format is not utf-8 bom

Answer (score 0):

Several examples how to extract data:

```
<dyn_variable name="id_1" jsonpath="$.content.id"/>

<dyn_variable name="id_2" jsonpath="$.content.[0].id"/>

<dyn_variable name="id_3" jsonpath="$.content.forms.array[?title=test].id"/>
```

See more examples:
https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

And check in realtime:
https://jsonpath.com/